# Compare a list of words in a spreadsheet with 'highlighted' words in a Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm looking for a "is this possible" answer before I dive into the "how" to do it.

Can a list of words in a Google Spreadsheet (answer key) be compared with only the "highlighted" words in a Google Document?

If yes, can a report be generated to tell me which "answer key" words were 'not' highlighted in the Google Document?

I'm a high school teacher and I'm looking for a way to evaluate large numbers of student work to see if they've identified key terms. I'd like to know if this is "possible" via Google AppScript before I attempt to build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can, and I already did it for you :D.  You can find the folder with relevant example files here:  https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_5rNbCI5MM9eXI2M005WVR1SUU&usp=sharing and the how is with this script which references the student's document submission and your answer key.

```
function findAnswersFromKey(){
  var fileId = '1nI4rIvexA87s0eRmPUTJWxDtVxyx8qZ9nwQUKiK6Q4U';
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(fileId);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1oikQnTcTx0KnCiwiy-pEUz9HLwLBh6ND4Xpo36xNS9o');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Planets Quiz Key');
  var answerRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,8,1);
  var targetAnswers = answerRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(targetAnswers);
  for (var i = 0; i < targetAnswers.length; i++){
    var target = targetAnswers[i];
    Logger.log(target);
    var targetBackground = sheet.getRange(i+2,1,1,1).getBackground();
    Logger.log(targetBackground);
    var answerCount = 0;
    var bodyElement = doc.getBody();
    var searchResult = bodyElement.findText(target);
    while (searchResult !== null) {
      var thisElement = searchResult.getElement();
      var thisElementText = thisElement.asText();
      thisElementText.setBackgroundColor(searchResult.getStartOffset(), searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),targetBackground);
      // search for next match
      searchResult = bodyElement.findText(target, searchResult);
      answerCount++;
      Logger.log(answerCount);
    }
    sheet.getRange(i+2,2,1,1).setValue(answerCount);
  }
  var studentId = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getOwner().getEmail();
  sheet.getRange(1,2,1,1).setValue(studentId+"'s Quiz Answer Count");
}
```

There are various ways to integrate this solution, such as a UiApp to upload a .docx file that is converted to a google document, folder.find("Planets Quiz"), etc., but I'll leave those to you to decide.

I used the getBackground() and setBackground methods to find the text elements (words) that match the answer key.  I also counted the matching elements so you can see how many times each is referenced.  You will notice that two of the planets are not discussed in the document, and have a count of 0.

Comment: THANK YOU! At first glance this looks "very close" to what I'm looking for. Do you know if you can use the answer key to identify the words in the document "only if" they are highlighted? I basically want to ignore all of the words in the text document 'except' the highlighted one.

Comment: I assumed the students were turning in an "unhighlighted" doc, so the script checks the answer key, and colors words based on the background color of the answer key's cell for that term). It then matches and counts the frequency of that particular color, ignoring all other words (because it's looking for colors at that point, not words). Where you may have some trouble is multi-word answers, but I assume you could check element combinations against a regexp in the key (to account for the spaces). But, as for your question, the answer is yes (if I understand what you're asking correctly).

Comment: Do you mind accepting this answer, if it answers your question?  Thanks!